# I can't understand how php evaluates this code

Tags: php

I came across this part of code somewhere and I don’t understand how both operations evaluate to 3

```
<?php
$x = 1;
$y = $x + $x++;
var_dump($y); // output : 3

$x = 1;
$y = $x + $x + $x++;
var_dump($y); // output : 3
```

what's going on? what am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined behavior and sequence points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: Seriously? downvote? I found a code I didn't understand so I came here to ask about. Thanks!

Comment: @AzizFCB If votes really bother you, just open up your browser console and change it, just don't reload the page anymore, *really don't* :)

Comment: tends to show up as a question asked in exams\job interviews to test knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As many times the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) holds also the answer for this:

> Operator precedence and associativity only determine how expressions are grouped, they do not specify an order of evaluation. **PHP does not (in the general case) specify in which order an expression is evaluated** and code that assumes a specific order of evaluation should be avoided, because the behavior can change between versions of PHP or depending on the surrounding code.

> Example #2 Undefined order of evaluation

```
<?php

    $a = 1;
    echo $a + $a++; // may print either 2 or 3

    $i = 1;
    $array[$i] = $i++; // may set either index 1 or 2
```

So as you can see maybe someone will get 2 first and not 3, since the order is not specified. That's all there is to it.